# Infinite well particle probability where it will most likely be found

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Suppose a particle is in the first excited state of an infinite square well of width $L$, where would the particle most likely be found if its position were measured?

---

So by looking at the probability density graph I can see that the particle will be most likely be found in between $\frac{L}{4}$ and $\frac{3L}{4}$ but is there a more specific computational way to found out instead of referring to the probability density graph? For example, if I want to know where a particle is most likely to be found for the second excited state then I can refer to the graph again and see that it will be most likely in between $\frac{L}{8}$ and $\frac{7L}{8}$  but what if I wanted to find the $50th$ excited state then looking at the graph will be complicated.

---

I know that the probability density is $$|\Psi(x)|^2=\frac{2}{L}\sin^2(\frac{n\pi x}{L}), \text{where $n$ is the particle's state}$$

but how do I use that to determine where the particle will most likely be found?

Comment: Have you taken any form of quantum mechanics? We should get a good idea of the level at which we should tailor our responses.

Comment: @Triatticus Not yet, this is a modern physics class which is a class we need to take right before taking quantum mechanics but the very last topic of the modern physics class introduces lightly to quantum mechanics with the particle in the box and Schrodinger wave equation.

Comment: Ah well that is certainly something you will learn (or should learn) near the start of a good QM course. I'm answering on mobile right now so I'll let someone else come up with a better response than this.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a discrete set of values for some quantity that we can measure $x$, then the average of those values can be expressed in terms of the probability of obtaining a particular value of $x$

$$\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}P(x_i)x_i,\qquad\qquad\qquad(1.1)$$

where $\bar{x}$ represents the average value, $N$ the number of measurements, and $P(x_i)$ the probability of measuring $x_i$. Now in your case, the wavefunction corresponds to a probability density amplitude the squared modulus of which is a probability density, which simply means $P(x_i)=|\Psi(x_i)|^2\Delta x$, such that $P(x_i)$ corresponds to the probability of finding a particle within a bin centred at $x_i$ and having a range $\Delta x$. Substituting $P(x_i)$ back into Eq.(1.1) and allowing $N\to\infty$, $x_i\to x$ and $\Delta x \to dx$ the summation turns into an integration and we find

$$\langle x\rangle = \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}x\sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx,\qquad\qquad\qquad(1.2)$$

where for the limit $N\to\infty$ we obtain the expectation of x, $\bar{x}_{N\to\infty}=\langle x\rangle$. I will let you do the integral Eq.(1.2).

Answer (score 0):

The particle is most likely to be found where the probability density is largest. So, find where the the probability density function is maximized using standard calculus methods.

Comment: The probability of hitting a specific value in a continuous probability distribution is zero.

Comment: @RogerVadim And? The particle is still most likely to be found near where the PDF is maximal.

Comment: @MarkH It depends on how you frame it. You technically do need to specify some sort of interval; in this case you are looking at any interval of length $\text dx$. But it's more likely to find the particle at any other location as opposed to a small region around the maximum of the probability distribution. Or to make an example, in a bag with 1 copper, 1 bronze, 1 silver, and 2 gold coins, gold is the most likely coin type you will get, but it's more likely that you will draw something other than gold. Saying "gold is most likely" could be true or false.